# Reference a Text File with relative path in Java with the IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, text, relative-path

I have a program that reads numbers from a `.txt` file. My problem is where to place this file, or how to reference it with a relative path to make this file accessible without using the absolute path.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you try to open a file, it takes your current working path.
For example this working tree:

```
Project
|->src
|   |-->MyClass.java
|   |-->MyFile1.txt
|->res
   |->files
     |-->MyFile2.txt
```

You can use `new File("MyFile1.txt");` for MyFile1.

or

`new File("./res/files/MyFile2.txt");` for MyFile2.

Comment: And of course import your text file to your working directory

Answer (score 7):

You need to start your path from src. "src/your/path/file.txt". See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50427103/6662058)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a multi-project setup, it may not be obvious what the "root" directory is for a relative path. In that case, open the `Terminal` tab in your IntelliJ and see what directory it lands in. That is the "root" directory. Your relative path should start there.

Comment: This was the answer that I am looking for! Thanks @Big Pumpkin

Answer (score 0):

@Big Pumpkin
Not sure about the terminal showing me the path of the "root".
But it does turn out to be the top most directory in a multi-module project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If file1.txt in 'src' it will have path as "src\main\java\file1.txt". Relative path starts from src.