# Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found in intellij idea

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, sessionfactory

I have some trouble with project that has been downloaded from remote repository.
It's maven project.

The structure of my folders are like:

```
db/
..src/
....main/
........java/
...........org.db/
..................Main.java
..................SessionFactoryUtil
..................(and PojoClasses)
...........hibernate.cfg.xml
..pom.xml
```

My SessionFactoryUtil class code :

```
package org.db;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class SessionFactoryUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

my pom.xml of this module

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>db</artifactId>
<name>db</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.26</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

parent pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Memorina</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.21</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <finalName>spring-webmvc</finalName>
</build>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>db</module>
    <module>model</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

Error :

```
12:11:58.198 [main] INFO  o.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version - Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
12:11:58.222 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.2.6
12:11:58.225 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
12:11:58.228 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : cglib
12:11:58.232 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.db.SessionFactoryUtil.buildSessionFactory(SessionFactoryUtil.java:23)
    at org.db.SessionFactoryUtil.<clinit>(SessionFactoryUtil.java:9)
    at org.db.App.createPerson(App.java:32)
    at org.db.App.main(App.java:14)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1411)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1433)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1420)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:966)
    at org.db.SessionFactoryUtil.buildSessionFactory(SessionFactoryUtil.java:18)
    ... 8 more

12:11:58.353 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
12:11:58.353 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration - Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Help me,please!

Comment: Where is hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Try moving `hibernate.cfg.xml` to `src/main/resources`

Comment: @PredragMaric folder resources is not exist,i may create my own this?

Comment: Yes, it is also part of standard maven folder structure.

Comment: @immibis it is located in the java/main

Comment: @PredragMaric no,problem not solved :(  project structure is generated without folder resources http://www.picshare.ru/view/6735933/

Comment: Don't have IDEA in front of me, but you should probably register `src/main/resources` as project's resource folder. Look for it in project properties, and check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717038/adding-resources-in-intellij-for-java-project) for hints how to do that

Comment: Great, glad you resolved it.