# Source not found importing CSS to JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, stylesheet

I'm working on a project where I'd like to use an external CSS file with JavaFX to style the VBox and panes and such.

I've used the line below to try to add the style sheet to the respective scene:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
```

This gave me null pointers, I read some other posts on this issue and found that this is often due to the stylesheet not being in the class path that it is trying to be accessed from. Here is a screenshot that allows you to see that this is not the case:

[image]

You'll notice there is Styles.css and style.css, I tried both for different troubleshooting purposes

I also found suggestions from people saying that if it is in the class path, that it should be accessed as such:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
```

However doing so is giving me

```
Nov 04, 2018 9:24:10 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
WARNING: Resource "Styles.css" not found.
```

I'm open to any suggestions, I'm working in IntelliJ using maven.

**EDIT: Here is the pom file for further investigation -**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.almasb</groupId>
<artifactId>CashMachine</artifactId>
<version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <source.version>1.8</source.version>

    <!-- plugins -->
    <maven.compiler.version>3.3</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.shade.version>2.4.2</maven.shade.version>

    <!-- dependencies -->
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${source.version}</source>
                <target>${source.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.almasb.atm.CashMachineApp</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you please let us know where is your class sitting in the heirarcy. Is it CashMachineApp ?

Comment: How are you building your app? Are you using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle? If so, resources should go in `src/main/resources` not `src/main/java`. Most build tools will ignore non `.java` files in the `src/main/java` directory by default.

Comment: Also, if you pass a `String` with no protocol to `getStylesheets().add(...)` it will look for it on the classpath—but it requires the _absolute path_.

Comment: @Slaw Yes I am using Maven, and the package is arranged the way I received it from my school. The class which is trying to use the stylesheet is CashMachineApp.

Comment: Check the `target/classes` directory to see if your CSS file(s) was copied there when you built the project.

Comment: I just checked and found it is not there, though I'm not really sure what this means? also, thank you for the quick response @Slaw

Comment: Can you post your POM file (`pom.xml`)? I'm thinking your school/class made a mistake putting the CSS files under `src/main/java`. Are other students having this problem?

Comment: I don't believe this to a mistake of the school, they essentially gave us an already created javaFX project and asked us to improve it somehow, I put the files in the java directory as I thought that is where it would be easiest to access.  I've updated with the pom.xml I believe you are speaking of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183100/discussion-between-jonathan-hinds-and-slaw).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maven convention uses a [standard directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and, unless otherwise configured, requires that you follow it. One of the things the standard directory layout does is separate Java source files (`.java`) from resource files (everything not `.java`). It looks like this:

```
|--projectDir/
|  |--src/
|  |  |--main/
|  |  |  |--java/
|  |  |  |--resources/
```

The source files go in `src/main/java` and the resource files go in `src/main/resources`.

When you build your project Maven will compile the source files and put the `.class` files in `projectDir/target/classes`. It will also copy any resource files from `src/main/resources` into `target/classes` as well. By default, any non-source files in `src/main/java` will be ignored. You mention you had put your `styles.css` file in `src/main/java` and thus it is not in `target/classes` when you run your project.

When you execute the project the directory `target/classes` (as well as any dependencies) is put on the classpath. But because your `styles.css` file wasn't copied into `target/classes` it is not included in the classpath and you end up getting `NullPointerException`s when trying to reference it.

The solution is to move the `styles.css` file into the `src/main/resources` directory. It looks like you currently have it under `src/main/java/rocks/zipcode/atm`. If you want to keep the resource file in the same "package" move it to `src/main/resources/rocks/zipcode/atm`. Then it should be copied to the `target/classes` directory when you rebuild your project.

Then you can reference it a couple of ways.

The first way is using `getClass().getResource(...)`. If you pass an absolute path (starts with a `/`) it will look for the resource from the root of the classpath. If you don't pass an absolute path (doesn't start with a `/`) it will look for the resource *relative to the `Class`'s location* (in this case, the `Class` is the one returned by `getClass()`). This means, since you're getting the resource from within `rocks.zipcode.atm.CacheMachineApp`, you could either do:

- `getClass().getResource("/rocks/zipcode/atm/styles.css")`, or
- `getClass().getResource("styles.css")`

The other option is to use the behavior defined in the documentation of `getStylesheets()`:

> Gets an observable list of string URLs linking to the stylesheets to use with this scene's contents.
>
> The URL is a hierarchical URI of the form [scheme:][//authority][path]. If the URL does not have a [scheme:] component, the URL is considered to be the [path] component only. Any leading '/' character of the [path] is ignored and the [path] is treated as a path relative to the root of the application's classpath.

As you can see, when there is no scheme (e.g. `file:`, `https:`, etc.) it will look for the resource relative to the *root of the the classpath*. Since it is always relative to the root you need to pass the absolute path (but in this case it doesn't require a leading `/`).

```
getStylesheets().add("rocks/zipcode/atm/styles.css");
```

**Important Note:** Make sure you get the path *completely* correct. It is case sensitive when packaged in a JAR file. It may or may not be case sensitive when not packaged in a JAR file, but that is dependent on the underlying file system. Either way, it is best to match the case of the actual path in order to avoid any problems.

Comment: You are a life saver @Slaw, your detailed explanation along with this post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717038/adding-resources-in-intellij-for-maven-project where exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for such a detailed response, I truly appreciate it mate.

Answer (score 0):

If your css file is sitting in the same package of your class:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toString());
```

Comment: This gave me a null pointer also, though thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was  adding "//" at the beginning of the 'path from content'
Like this:"//src/practice/Viper.css"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31152642)